# how to create select box from a given list in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am passing a list from my controller

```
 @distinct_grade_list = Student.uniq.pluck(:grade)
```

which creates  the distinct list of grades from model Student

now in my view page , how can i display it as select box
I am using

```
<%= collection_select(A, @distinct_grade_list, B, C, D) %>
```

now what do i have to keep at A,B,C,D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}) public
```

why not read the [api document and sample](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)?

sample usage:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  def name_with_initial
    "#{first_name.first}. #{last_name}"
  end
end

collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, :prompt => true)
```

and result:

```
<select name="post[author_id]">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">D. Heinemeier Hansson</option>
  <option value="2">D. Thomas</option>
  <option value="3">M. Clark</option>
</select>
```

**The value returned from calling method on the instance object will be selected**

call :author_id on :post, @post is you passed from controller

**The :value_method and :text_method parameters are methods to be called on each member of collection. The return values are used as the value attribute and contents of each  tag, respectively.**

:id is value_method
:name_with_initial is text_method
collection is used to populated "options"

Comment: take a look at this example http://www.brentsowers.com/2007/11/using-selecttag-to-make-form-select.html