# I want to create a select using rails instead of html

Tags: select

I'm creating a site using rails that allows users to enter recipes into a database. They will do so by selecting ingredients from a select html form item. Those ingredients came from a database where I've stored all of the ingredients on a table calls Ingredients. This is an outline example of my code but using html:

```
<select name="ingrediente">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Tomato</option>
  <option value="2">Potato</option>
  <option value="3">Onion</option>
</select>
```

This ingredients can change by the time. Ingredients table has two columns. Name and IngredientID. The value should be the id, and the name should be what is printed to the screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create select box from a given list in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229947/how-to-create-select-box-from-a-given-list-in-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using a form in rails:

```
<% form_for @ingredients do |f|%>
  <%= f.collection_select(:ingredient, Ingredients.all, :id, :name) %>
<% end %>
```

- :ingredient => is the column where you will save this ingredient
- Ingredients.all => is a query of all the ingredients that you want to
  be on the selection.
- :id => is the value of the each option
- :name => is the column information that will appear on the select as name of the option

Comment: Thanks man, this works. I have to fix some things of how to save it but this actually worksss xD